# shutdown Apache Ignite gracefully

Tags: shell, unix, ignite

I am having Apache ignite in Linux server and looking for a graceful shutdown of the ignite server.

Currently I am doing grep and killing the process, but looking for command so that I can make a script.

```
./ignite.sh -J-DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true
```

I found this from google but is there a way I don't want to wait for backup and exit it.

Any inputs would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Graceful shutdown implies that Ignite will perform some additional cleanup and maintenance routines while stopping a node, this is called a shutdown hook. As the [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/starting-nodes#shutting-down-nodes) stay there are several ways of stopping a node gracefully:

- programmatically call Ignite.close()
- programmatically call System.exit()
- send a user interrupt signal. Ignite uses a JVM shutdown hook to execute custom logic before the JVM stops. If you start the node by running ignite.sh and don’t detach it from the terminal, you can stop the node by hitting Ctrl+C

Killing a process by sending kill -9 sig will not trigger the shutdown hook and might cause some issues up to data corruption in some corner cases.

Configuring `J-DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true` or `ShutdownPolicy.Graceful` (which is the same) explicitly forces an additional backup consistency check to ensure that a node won't leave the cluster if this would lead to partition loss, i.e. if both primary and backup (if any) partitions left the grid, check [this doc](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/starting-nodes#preventing-partition-loss-on-shutdown) for a more detailed explanation. This is something that you won't turn off in most cases and I recommend you to keep this setting.

But, if you don't need backups validation, you can just remove `J-DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true` and send SIGINT to the Java process.

In order to check that a node is stopping gracefully, you should see the following message in the log:

```
[INFO][shutdown-hook] Invoking shutdown hook...
```